# Why don't I see posts from my family members in my stream?

Tags: google-plus

I have a Family circle with 7 members.  I have my subscription level for this circle set to the highest setting: "Also subscribe to notifications for all new posts".  Yet, on several occasions, family members have posted things, and these things do not show up in any of my streams.

I have gotten notifications when my family members post things, and I can see the posts if I go to their profiles directly, but scrolling through my Home stream or my Family stream I do not see their posts.

Why is this?  Is this a known issue, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, added this comment to an answer, should be attached to question: @Eric can you have your wife share something with just you? Perhaps this is indeed a bug with sharing with you in a circle. Let's try to isolate the problem by removing the circle sharing complexity.

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter, thanks for the suggestion - I'll try it, and other variations this weekend.

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter, after trying several times unsuccessfully to reproduce this today, I discovered that the problem seems to have been resolved.  I went through my family stream, and old posts that used to not show up are now showing up.  As far as I can tell, all of my posts now show up correctly.  Must have been a bug that got fixed, I guess.

Comment: sounds good Eric, glad it was resolved for you!

Comment: Facebook has an Acquaintances group, and anyone in that group is limited in the feed. Google+ has the same default circle, but 1) I don't know if your family is in it (too) and 2) I don't know if it works the same way as Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Family stream:

[image]

Check if you have subscribed to all posts:

[image]

If you still do not see all posts from your family members, I guess you must report it as a bug, unless you have a lot of people in your other circles and/or the volume of posts generated by one or more person/page is high enough for Google+'s algorithm to not be able to display all posts on your home screen. And there are chances that the updates you are looking for are overshadowed by all other posts (you might have to look deep).

Comment: Eric already mentioned his notification settings are set to "Also subscribe to notifications for all new posts," so this is not a slider issue.

Comment: Then the other possible reason could be the *high volume* of posts from others who he follows. There is no other reason i can think off.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish, unfortunately that's not it - I have an extremely low volume of posts.  Particularly in my Family stream, they are almost all from me (a couple of posts per week).

Comment: you could do one thing - ask 2 3 of your family members to post something to the family circle. See if it appears in your feed. Basically prove that its not working. It could happen that you were true about the finding, or you may realize that it was all in the mind (Sometimes people do say they've shared something, but may be referring to an old post or missing something)

Comment: @AbhishekGirish, I have proved this several times.  Just today, my wife posted something.  I can't see it in my family stream, or anywhere in any of my streams, but I *can* see it if I go directly to her page.  In every case, I can verify that my family member has indeed posted something by simply going to their page directly.

Comment: Can you see the posts in your stream at a later point of time? I mean can you check if you are having issues with real-time updates only? http://support.google.com/plus/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs - Stream

Comment: @AbhishekGirish, no the problem posts never show up in my streams.

Comment: Its very strange. I've never faced this issue - may be its a bug. Did you report it to Google?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been added by them into their circles?
Adding a person to your circle means you can share posts with them.
The only exception is the circle labeled 'Following' where you can add people whose posts you want to follow.

Just check if your family members have added you into their circles.

Comment: Yes, they have - otherwise, I wouldn't be able to see their posts when I go directly to their profile.